# While going through the mcqs of Techgig event in india i had problem on the following code. Help me understand the following code

Tags: c++, constructor, static

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class abc
{
    static int x;
    public:
        abc()
        {
            x++;
        }
    static int getx()
    {
        return x;

    }
};
int abc::x=0;
int main()
{
    cout<<abc::getx()<<" ";
    abc t[10];
    cout<<abc::getx();

}
```

While going through the mcqs of Techgig event in india i had problem on the following code. Help me understand the following code.
what does the line abc t[10] means?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a substitue to reading a good introductory book on C++. [Here's a selection of several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Comment: What is an "mcq"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what does the line abc t[10] means?

It means that you get 10 `abc` on the stack and that you will refer to them by `t`. Just like `int t[10]` gets you 10 `int`, except instead of `int`, it's `abc`.

But you probably wondered what this example is supposed to demonstrate with it. We have a static variable in class `abc`, so this one exists only **once**, no matter how many `abc` are made:

```
static int x;
```

It is set to 0 here:

```
int abc::x=0;
```

At the start of the program we confirm that it indeed is 0:

```
cout<<abc::getx()<<" ";
```

This should print `0`, because it's calling a static getter that returns that x value:

```
static int getx()
{
    return x;
}
```

Now, what's happening here?

```
abc t[10];
```

Here, 10 `abc` are made. Actually, in reality not much might be made here because `abc` doesn't have any non-static fields. But nevertheless, the constructor is called every time:

```
abc()
{
    x++;
}
```

Remember, 10 `abc` are made, so this is called 10 times. Thus, `x` is increased by `1` ten times, and since it was `0`, it should now be `10`. We confirm this assumption with the following print:

```
cout<<abc::getx();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It helped me.